# Read filename with * shell bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, variables, filenames

I'am new in Linux and I want to write a bash script that can read in a file name of a directory that starts with LED + some numbers.(Ex.: LED5.5.002)

In that directory there is only one file that will starts with LED. The problem is that this file will every time be updated, so the next time it will be for example LED6.5.012 and counting.

I searched and tried a little bit and came to this solution:

```
export fspec=/home/led/LED*
LedV=`basename $fspec`
echo $LedV
```

If I give in those commands one by one in my terminal it works fine, LedV= LED5.5.002 but if i run it in a bash scripts it gives the result: LedV = LED*

I search after another solution:

`a=/home/led/LED*`
`LedV=$(basename $a)`
`echo $LedV`

but here again the same, if i give it in one by one it's ok but in a script: LedV = LED*.

It's probably something small but because of my lack of knowledge over Linux I cannot find it. So can someone tell what is wrong?

Thanks! Jan

Comment: /home/led/LED* expands to all of the matches of /home/led/LED<something>. So for example if you say `ls /home/led/LED*` you will get all of them (one, in your case). I would debug saying `var=/home/led/LED*`. And then `echo $var` to confirm it is expanding properly.

Comment: `a=/home/led/LED* LedV=$(basename $a) echo $LedV` cannot work from same line. Try: `a=/home/led/LED* LedV=$(basename $a); echo "$LedV"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shell expansions don't happen on scalar assignments, so in

```
varname=foo*
```

the expansion of `"$varname"` will literally be `"foo*"`. It's more confusing when you consider that `echo $varname` (or in your case `basename $varname`; either way without the double quotes) will cause the *expansion* itself to be treated as a glob, so you may well think the variable contains all those filenames.

Array expansions are another story. You might just want

```
fspec=( /path/LED* )
echo "${fspec[0]##*/}" # A parameter expansion to strip off the dirname
```

That will work fine for bash. Since POSIX sh doesn't have arrays like this, I like to give an alternative approach:

```
for fspec in /path/LED*; do
    break
done
echo "${fspec##*/}"
```

Comment: Hello, sorry for the late respons but was away for the weekend.

Comment: fspec=( /path/LED* )
echo "${fspec[0]##*/}"

Comment: "${fspec##*/}" works but the problem is that fspec reads in the path name but remembers now the /path/LED* and not for example /path/LED5.5.345.

Comment: and as you mentioned their is really no option to use the LED* on scalar assignments. Thanks for the aid I will try to find a knew option!

Answer (score 1):

```
pwd
/usr/local/src

ls -1 /usr/local/src/mysql*
    /usr/local/src/mysql-cluster-gpl-7.3.4-linux-glibc2.5-x86_64.tar.gz
    /usr/local/src/mysql-dump_test_all_dbs.sql
```

if you only have 1 file, you will only get 1 result

```
MyFile=`ls -1 /home/led/LED*`
```